# How to set no border when drawing background colored rectange?

Tags: pdfclown

Is there a way to set no border when drawing background-color filled rectangle?  Or make border color match background-color filled rectange?

```
PrimitiveComposer primitiveComposer = new PrimitiveComposer(page);
{
    BlockComposer blockComposer = new BlockComposer(primitiveComposer);

    primitiveComposer.SetLineWidth(0.0f);
    primitiveComposer.SetFillColor(DeviceRGBColor.Get(System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray));
    primitiveComposer.DrawRectangle(new RectangleF(_boxMarginX, _boxMarginY, (page.Size.Width - (_boxMarginX * 2)), 205f), 0f);
    primitiveComposer.FillStroke();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use

```
primitiveComposer.FillStroke();
```

which is the command to fill and stroke a path. As you don't want the borders, i.e. you don't want to stroke, use

```
primitiveComposer.Fill();
```

instead.

By the way,

```
primitiveComposer.SetLineWidth(0.0f);
```

The PDF specification defines a line width of 0 to mean the smallest line the target device can render.

Comment: I see.  I didn't know what Stroke mean.  I thought it was just a programmer wording to define an object.  Thanks man!